# Form Repeater - angular

Tags: angular

I tried to use jquery.repeater(npm install jquery.repeater) to apply form repeater in angular but it didn't. Is there other solutions or a way to work with (jquery.repeater)
[image: Repeater]

Comment: Angular combined with jQuery is not a good combination. It would be fairly easy to build this in pure Angular.

Comment: @MikeOne do you have any link or demo that can help

Comment: avoid using of jQuery in the angular project, just you will need to read about *ngFor directive and Reactive Forms(for this case you can use FormArray), 

1. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms
2. https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can implement this using pure Angular. Here is one:

In the component ts have the following

```
constructor(
      private formBuilder : FormBuilder
) { }
 
formInfoHolder = [];

onAdd(){
    let newForm = {
        username : new FormControl(''),
        password : new FormControl(''),
        gender : new FormControl(''),
        profession : new FormControl('')
    }
    this.formInfoHolder.push(this.formBuilder.group(newForm))
}
delete(toDelete){
    let aux : any[] = [];
    for(let form of this.formInfoHolder){
       if(toDelete !== form){
            aux.push(form);
       }
    }
    this.formInfoHolder = aux;
}
```

Then, in the component html

```
<div *ngFor="let form of formInfoHolder">
     <form [formGroup]="form">
         <label for="username"> Username </label>
         <input id="username" type="text" formControlName="username">
         <!-- insert other input elements with the formControlName -->
         <label for="delete"> Delete </label>
         <input id="delete" type="button" (click)="delete(form)">
     </form>
</div>
<button (click)="onAdd()">Add</button>
```

With this implementation, you have to import the ReactiveFormsModule in your app.module.ts

If you need additional explanation feel free to ask.

Comment: That's a real nice approach, thanks so much