# How do i iterate over the input field names and values in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a form controls dynamically based on the dynamic data for the below model

```
{"name": "firstName"},
{"name": "lastName" }

<form [formGroup]="myForm" #formDirective="ngForm" >
    <div *ngFor="let n of data">
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
                  <mat-select required [(value)]="selected" name="{{n.name}}">
                    <mat-option value="equal" >Equals</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="notequal">Not Equals</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
        
                <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                  <input matInput name="{{n.name}}"> 
                </mat-form-field> 
    </div>
</form>
```

i want to send this dynamic data for which i need to iterate over the fields and get the name and value of the field.

i tried the below code, but no luck.. can someone please help me

```
myForm: any;
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.array([]); 
    Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach((name) => {
          let currentControl = this.myForm.controls[name];
    
            console.log("name: " + name, "value: " +currentControl.value);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the formBuilder you can use `this.formBuilder.group()`, something like:

```
args;
myForm;

startFormGroup(args){
   this.args = args;
   let aux = {};
   for(let arg of args){
      aux[arg] = new FormControl('');
   }
   myForm = this.formBuilder.group(aux);
}
```

Then, in the html you can use something like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form.form" #formDirective="ngForm">
   <div *ngFor="let arg  of args">    
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <input matInput name="{{arg}}" formControlName="{{arg}}"> 
        </mat-form-field> 
    </div>
 </form>
```

Please note, that this is a template and I have not tested the code.

See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72050877/17503046) question for another similar example.

Fell free to ask for clarification if needed.

Comment: thanks Manuel. In my case there is only one form and the input controls are generating dynamically based on the db data. for example it might generate fields for firstName, lastName and age. All i want is firstname:Jack, lastName: Daniel, age: 34

Comment: Based on your example, you have multiple forms, as *ngFor is outside the form, thats why I gave the example this way. When you say you only want something like firstname:Jack, lastName: Daniel, age: 34, does it mean that the equal/not equal select is not needed?

Comment: yes, if i can get it for one control.. i can figure out the other one easily :). I have also corrected the code in the question

Comment: see if the edited answer is what you are looking for. note that startFormGroup can receive an array with all the args you want

Comment: Sorry, i am very new to angular and its giving error at line aux[arg]= new FormControl(''). Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Comment: I think what you need to do to solve this issue is to put `let aux : any = {}`. Notice the `:any`. This happens because Angular will have the "noImplicitAny" verification for default when you create the project. If you want to deactivate this option just add `"noImplicitAny":false` in the `compilerOptions` of your tsconfig.json file

Comment: Thank you so much Manuel Tomas. I was struggling on this for a while